# How to change location sorting? (Wordpress, Triply Theme)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[This is the list of the booking locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGER1.png), I need to change sorting of them to sort by slug, maybe anybody know how to change it.
thank you in advance

I tried to search and find the exact file in theme editor and also in plugin editor. plugin is: ba book everything

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to functions.php.  Adjust it with the post type of the booking locations and set ASC or DESC.

```
function trojanist_order_booking_locations_by_slug( $query ){
  if( $query->get('post_type') == 'booking_location_post_type_slug' ){
    $query->set('orderby', 'name');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'trojanist_order_booking_locations_by_slug');
```

Comment: fact is this is not a post this is an array which's have to sorted, and + what should i write instead of trojanist?

Comment: People will need to see the text output of your array to tell you how to sort it.  If this is a php array, use a print_r or var_dump function to output it.  If this is a javascript array, console.log it.  Copy/paste the result into your question and it should be pretty easy to answer.

Comment: Also, if this is created by a plugin in WordPress, and there is a way for you to add/edit/delete these in the WordPress dashboard, then there is a post type created for these and you can use the code above if you can determine what that post type is.